# javascript navigation input similar to amazon.com but 3 levels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your input on replacing our navigation.

in nzxt.com   you 'll see how we have 3 level of top navigation.

Level 1 -> level 2 -> level 3

and it could support pictures too.

However this is build using css. So when the mouse is outside the area, the navigation will close automatically (cannot use delay).

In order to apply delay, I have to use javascript.

The problem is it's difficult to find jquery that can do 3 level navigation. The one that we like is like amazon.com.

but that's at most 2 levels.  I might have to create this myself, but if I can find something that's already out there, it's much better.

Thus, I need your help if you have found or worked on jquery that would support this navigation (at least 3 level).

Any links or advice would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Superfish should meet your needs http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following menu by Chris Coyier. It has a hoverintent version too which is probably what you are looking for. You need to style it according to your need though. It should not be too difficult to make your own too.

[[Link](http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/)]

Comment: Thank you for your response. the css solution won't work because the delay won't apply. furthermore the sample only works for 2 level while I need at least 3 level. Perhaps any other javascript solution?

Comment: The one I posted before has a JS version down below, titled under hoverintent.